# How to parse nested xml in spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark version - 2.2 and java 1.8

I want to parse an XML (which is nested) in spark with java and create a Spark Dataset out of it.

I tried using databricks xml library, which is not giving me expected output(nested tags are not removed).

Below is the XML format.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE record SYSTEM "dcr4.5.dtd">
<record type="content" name="ON_2014529152858875">
<item name="provinces">
<value>AL_</value>
</item>
<item name="img_zone">
<value>LOGOS</value>
</item>
<item name="language">
<value>en</value>
</item>
<item name="product_line">
<value>tv</value>
</item>
<item name="en_image_array">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="fixed_html">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="english">
<value>
<item name="product_type">
<value>abc</value>
</item>
<item name="product_info">
<value>
<item name="product_title">
<value>title1</value>
</item>
<item name="product_ID">
<value>Z123</value>
</item>
<item name="display_order">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="short_desc">
<value>This is tv. <br /> <a href="www.abc.org" target="_blank">www.abc.org</a> </value>
</item>
<item name="channel_long_desc">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="new_short_desc">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="new_long_desc">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="package_features">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="hd_programming">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="on_demand">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="most_popular"/>
<item name="channel_exclusive"/>
<item name="shows">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="short_desc2"/>
<item name="long_desc"/>
<item name="movie_clip">
<value>
<item name="browser_selection"/>
<item name="file_from_local">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="file_from_teamsite">
<value/>
</item>
</value>
</item>
<item name="movie_clip_source">
<value>
<item name="browser_selection"/>
<item name="file_from_local">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="file_from_teamsite">
<value/>
</item>
</value>
</item>
<item name="genres"/>
<item name="channel_include"/>
<item name="premium_channel"/>
</value>
</item>
<item name="product_images1">
<value>
<item name="browser_selection"/>
<item name="image_from_local">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="image_from_teamsite">
<value/>
</item>
</value>
</item>
<item name="new_product_images1">
<value>
<item name="browser_selection">
<value>server</value>
</item>
<item name="image_from_local">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="image_from_teamsite">
<value>path1.png</value>
</item>
</value>
</item>
<item name="product_images2">
<value>
<item name="browser_selection">
<value>server</value>
</item>
<item name="image_from_local">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="image_from_teamsite">
<value>path2.png</value>
</item>
</value>
</item>
<item name="product_images3">
<value>
<item name="browser_selection">
<value>server</value>
</item>
<item name="image_from_teamsite">
<value>path3.png</value>
</item>
</value>
</item>
</value>
</item>
<item name="publish_attributes">
<value>
<item name="message">
<value/>
</item>
<item name="unpublish"/>
</value>
</item>
</record>
```

if we don't find value for column,"null" is acceptable.

Much appreciated in advance.Thanks.